# PCB soldermask removed in spots?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

I was watching a video on Youtube, where I came across this bottom side of a PCB:

[image]

*source: [EEVblog 1481 - Dodgy Dangerous Heater REPAIR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myqiqUE00fo)*

It is seen that the soldermask is removed so they can tin the tracks for better current carrying capabilities.

What's up with all these tinned 'spots', like in the upper right corner of the PCB, as well as parallel to the wide tinned trace? Are they also for reducing the trace resistance? Why didn't they just remove the soldermask across the whole copper pour/trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would have removed all the soldermask, but the resuling "blob" would have been

1. too thick, and
2. unequal, since the surface tension would have pulled all the solder to the middle to form a large "drop". So, you'd have more solder in the middle than you need, and less than you wanted at the edges.